# elisp: how to dump all environment variables

Tags: elisp

I can get a specific environment variable with the following lisp code

```
(getenv "HOME")
```

How can I dump all environment variables?

I tried

```
(getenv)
```

and also

```
(getenv "")
```

without success

Comment: Did you ask Emacs? `C-h f getenv` tells you about the arguments it accepts, and about the `process-environment` variable. There's almost never any reason to *guess* at elisp function arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the variable `process-environment`:

> process-environment is a variable defined in 'C source code'.
>   Its value is
>   `("TERM=dumb" "TZ=Europe/London"`  ...

Comment: `C-h v <enter>`, which prompts "Describe variable:", and enter `process-environment <enter>`